# Graph Api v2.2 Profile Object of facebook user for custom story?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, profile

I am working on a facebook game and I want to give the player the option to share a custom story of this kind:

**UserA Name** beat a person on **Game**
UserB Profile with description
[Image Example](http://www.spahar.me/customStory.png)

According to my research I should define this custom story in my App Dashboard, defining the action **beat** and the object **profile** (which is already provided by facebook). I did all these.

Now using JS SDK I should do something like this:

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'share_open_graph',
    action_type: 'namespace:beat',
    action_properties: JSON.stringify({
        profile: profile_url or profile object,
    })
}, function(response){});
```

The problem I am encountering is that I cannot find a way to provide a functional profile object. First I tried giving as profile_url something like http: //www.facebook.com/userb_id, but this does not work because the user_id is app specific. I have no other way of building this link, through the new api username of user is not provided as part of profile edge, and I cannot understand what's the use of the link given from profile edge ( http: //www.facebook.com/app_scope_id/user_id). Finally, I tried to create self hosted profile object and I succeded to some extend. I use the info from the profile edge (name, picture etc) to build the meta tags for the object. All went well except from the profile picture, which doesn't work cause the facebook **scraper** complains that the pic is from Facebook CDN.

So, how can I provide to the share dialog a functional profile object using the user info I have? I thought that this should be quite easy (easier than custom story with custom object-which I made it work) because it's something that Facebook already has (meaning the profile of UserB),so providing only an user_id should be enough.

Any ideas on what should I do? Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE!!!!!!!!!!!**

I made some progress but still I am encountering a problem. I have found a way to post the custom story but only through api post, not share dialog. This is very confusing.

This code works, but requires publish_actions permisions:

```
FB.api('/me/namespace:beat', 'post', {
    profile: 'user_b_id',
    'fb:explicitly_shared': true
}, function(response) {
    console.log('Open graph action via API', response);
});
```

This code doesn't work:

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'share_open_graph',
             action_type: 'namespace:beat',
             action_properties: {
                profile: 'user_b_id',
                'fb:explicitly_shared': true
             }
}, function(response) {
    console.log('Open graph action via API', response);
});
```

It returns an error in the attempt of opening the share dialog window, the error is: error_code: 100, error_message: "Could not resolve object at URL user_b_id."

Any ideas why FB can't resolve the object, but when posting the custom story with the first code block the object is resolved?

**UPDATE 2**

After submitting the problem to facebook it actually proved to be a bug. It is fixed now.